# Ist there a workaround for JMS / Websphere MQ message segmentation?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

So far I didn't find a solution to read segmented messages with IBM's JMS implementation (without message grouping). See also: [is IBM MQ Message Segmentation possible using JMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134485/is-ibm-mq-message-segmentation-possible-using-jms)

Ist there any workaround for a JMS client yet to receive segmented messages?

For e.g. is it possible to configure a "MQ server component" to reassemble segmented messages into one single message for the JMS client? Other ideas?

Comment: You could take a look at camel, to aggregate the messages in-memory in the endpoint. Would that suit you?

Comment: Do you have any links for details? Does camel support websphere mq segmentation?

Comment: Camel is built on a higher level. So you'd have camel pick up the messages from the JMS queue using http://camel.apache.org/jms.html and then aggregate them in the camel aggregator http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html .

Answer (score 2):

If the total reassembled message stays within 100MB (i.e. the maximum allowed message size), then you could have an interim queue with a non JMS MQ API application getting and reassembling the messages and then putting the large reassembled message onto a queue that the JMS application gets from. This would retain the smaller sized messages while they traverse though the MQ network, and are only large (read inefficient) messages at the last point before the application retrieves them.

However, if the total reassembled message is larger than 100MB, which may be the case if segments are in use then the above solution will not help.

In fact, if the total reassembled message is larger than 100MB then you can't send it over a client connection anyway, in which case you'll need to make th application local to the queue manager.

If you are local to a queue manager, then an API exit that changes the underlying MQGET call made by the JMS layer may also be a possibility. You can only use this if you have a local queue manager because client side API Exits are only supported in the C Client. You could cross the SVRCONN channel regardless of the type of client at the other end of the socket, but you cannot send a message greater than 100MB over the client channel so if the total reassembled message is greater than the channel's `MAXMSGL` then it can't be sent.

**Related Reading**

- [Writing API Exits](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q027930_.htm)
- [API Exit Reference](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q109600_.htm)

Comment: Do you have any links regarding 'API exit'? Why do I have to be local to the queue manager for API exits?

Comment: Added links and further explanation to the answer text